# Understanding of "background process" in Oracle documentation

Tags: oracle, process

On the *Oracle Concepts* documentation page at https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/intro.htm#CNCPT947. It describe background processes as:

> These processes consolidate functions that would otherwise be handled
>   by multiple Oracle Database programs running for each client process.

I don't quite understand it. Could anyone help to explain a little bit please? Thanks.

Comment: Did you follow the 'see also' link to chapter 15, which would lead you to [an overview of background processes](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/process.htm#CNCPT1249)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In simple words, they are trying to say that each client process has code in it that talks to the background processes, in order to coordinate communication between the server software (RDBMS) and all the client processes.

Without this "API" code, each client process would have to be a set of programs that talk back to the RDBMS.  This would not only be memory hungry and very inefficient, there would also not be coordination between server and client.